Error during `gcloud app deploy` for GAE app: "Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket"
After creating a new Google Cloud project and following all steps carefully from this documentation to create & deploy a new GAE app, gcloud app deploy yields the following error:
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 12 files to Google Cloud Storage               ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build:
com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: <eye3 title='/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild, FAILED_PRECONDITION'/>
APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild;invalid bucket
"staging.<myproject-id-redacted>.appspot.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account
does not have access to the bucket;AppErrorCode=9;StartTimeMs=1720838040970;unknown;ResFormat=uncompressed;ServerTimeSec=
1.2677860490000001;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=none;ReqFormat=uncompressed;ReqID=
929904cf53cd5131;GlobalID=0;Server=[2002:a05:6220:101:b0:4:6180:ab19]:4001.

It looks like this has been an issue reported before, with similar posts like this pointing to outages (doesn't seem like there is one reported at this time). Other posts like this one recommend turning on other apis & services and granting additional permissions to service accounts. I have tried all of these recommendations (i.e. turning on additional apis, granting/confirming permissions to the bucket for the service account in question, etc) but to no avail.
Something definitely feels broken and/or there is some missing documentation. Fwiw it's also frustrating that there is no way to get in touch with anyone at Google without paying $30/month for technical support, so I hope someone from the GCP team sees this - either some part of the service is down or the documentation likely needs to be updated.

Try again in a few hours. If you're still encountering the issue, post to Google Cloud Serverless Community and a Google staff will probably escalate it or post to the reddit group

Thanks @NoCommandLine, I posted a question on the Serverless forum but it looks like it's still pending review by the moderators. Posted on reddit but haven't had engagement from anyone on the Google team https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/1e2hbzd/new_google_app_engine_projects_cannot_be_deployed/. I've tried many times to deploy and attempt to fix service account permissions but am still running into the same errors despite both service accounts (default AppEngine & Cloud Build) having the right roles/permissions.

@myconode  I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Thank you @SupriyaBharti I left a comment below in your answer

Per this doc there are some change to App Engine's default service account (namely, on 5/23/2024, Google changed default global permissions for new organizations, in particular disabling iam.automaticIamGrantsForDefaultServiceAccounts).
As of now, these roles  required in the default service account to enable  gcloud app deploy:

Artifact Registry Create-on-Push Writer
Storage Admin
Logs Writer


Thank you Supriya, with your help I was able to figure it out. I wrote up a summary of the issue here with the necessary permissions to fix the problem (https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Error-during-gcloud-app-deploy-for-GAE-app-quot-Failed-to-create/m-p/778778/highlight/true#M4156). If you update your post with some of the details (namely permissions) I'll accept your answer so you get credit for it here. Thanks again for the link, that was critical information.

@myconode Thank you for coming back to the issue. I am glad the answer helped. As per your suggestion I have updated the answer. Can you please have a look?

This behaviour happens because Google has disabled the permissions given to the "App Engine default service accont" by default.
So another solution will be reversing this security measure by adding permission again.
It might not be the best solution for big enterprise setups where restricting permissions should be the way to go, but you can do so for minor personal / testing projects (which is my case).

Below the IAM and admin section in Google Cloud Console, go to Service Accounts.
Click on the Email in the row where the Name is "App Engine default service account"
Copy the Email from the row whose Name is "App Engine default service account"
Go to the PERMISSIONS tab and click GRANT ACCESS below the VIEW BY PRINCIPALS section.
Paste the Email address. You will see that the autocomplete labels this address as "App Engine default service account", select it.
When clicking in the Role dropdown, in the scrollable section below "By product or service" find "Project" and select it.
Select also the role "Editor" from the right column.
Save and deploy again (this action might take few minutes).

